# Using react native on attached device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to run the React Native not on simulator but on actual attached device. I am getting Xcode error when running `npx react-native run-ios --device "My iPhone"`

```
error: Signing for "AwesomeProjectTests" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'AwesomeProjectTests' from project 'AwesomeProject')
error: "AwesomeProject" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
```

Do I really need to pay 99 USD per year for developer account to enable to run the application and test it on my attached iPhone?

Surely there must be some other way. Btw official documentation of React Native doesn't mention anything. https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#2-configure-code-signing

Comment: I managed to find a page https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/ for Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, but it returns `Access Unavailable This resource is only for developers enrolled in a developer program or members of an organization’s team in a developer program.` The issue here is, that I really can not develop on my devices without paid Apple certificate lol.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of Bundle Identifier from default name to a different unique name and it started to work.
[image: Bundle Identifier React Native Xcode]